# linq query form

Tags: c#, linq

How can be the following code converted to linq or predicate expression:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
List<int> list2= new List<int> {2,3,4,5,6,7};
foreach (int int1 in list1)
 list2.Remove(int1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
list1.ForEach( x => { list2.Remove(x); } );
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
list2 = list2.Except(list1)
             .ToList();
```

This also will perform better than your original code, since your code is O(n<sup>2</sup>) doing a loop over all items in the first collection, then trying to find the first match in the second collection. (Although admittedly the performance difference will not matter much if your collections are this small, but it will matter significantly for large collections).

`Except()` will create a `HashSet<int>` of `list1` internally and then just traverse the `list2` collection. Only items that are not contained in the `HashSet` end up in the result enumeration - since the `HashSet` lookup is O(1) on average this will result in O(n) effort all in all.

For an educational refresher see Jon Skeets EduLinq series, here the [chapter for Except](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/17-Except.html).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the wonderful explanation. I learn something new on SO everyday.

Answer (score 1):

```
list2.RemoveAll(m=>list1.Contains(m));
```