# Remove elements from one List<T> that are found in another

Tags: c#

I have two lists

```
 List<T> list1 = new List<T>();
 List<T> list2 = new List<T>();
```

I want remove all elements from list1, which also exist in list2. Of course I can loop through the first loop looking for each element in list2, but I am looking for elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Except() function [There is a similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182123/linq-query-form/9182183#9182183)

Comment: Seek elegance in your titles, pls.

Comment: @halit: How many more times are you going to try and add the same comment?  Listen, here's how to create links in comments-- `[link text](url starting with http://)` This, and more information, can be found by reading our [faq].

Answer (score 43):

To change the actual list1 in place, you could use

```
list1.RemoveAll(item => list2.Contains(item));
```

You might instead prefer to simply have a query over the lists without modifying either

```
var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

LukeH makes a good recommendation in the comments. In the first version, and if list2 is particularly large, it might be worth it to load the list into a `HashSet<T>` prior to the `RemoveAll` invocation. If the list is small, don't worry about it. If you are unsure, test both ways and then you will know.

```
var theSet = new HashSet<YourType>(list2);
list1.RemoveAll(item => theSet.Contains(item));
```

Comment: +1. Also worth mentioning that if `list2` contains many items then it might make sense to create a temporary `HashSet<T>` and use that for the `Contains` call in your first example. The entire process then becomes O(m+n) rather than O(m*n). (And that's pretty much exactly what the LINQ `Except` method in your second example does internally.)

Answer (score 8):

With LINQ:

```
var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
list1.RemoveAll( item => list2.Contains(item));
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

I think you mean the generic type `List<Type>`. You can use `Linq` to do this

#### Sample

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
List<string> l2 = new List<string>();

l.Add("one");
l.Add("two");
l.Add("three");

l2.Add("one");
l2.Add("two");
l2.Add("three");
l2.Add("four");

l2.RemoveAll(x => l.Contains(x));
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - List.RemoveAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ you can do this:

```
 List1.RemoveAll(i => !List2.Contains(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a list of objects (`list2`) from another list (`list1`) use:

```
list1 = list1.Except(list2).ToList()
```

Remember to use `ToList()` to convert `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var NewList = FirstList.Where(a => SecondList.Exists(b => b.ID != a.ID));
```

Using LINQ