# How to get Unique objects from two lists in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two list objects like

```
list1   =[{"id":"101","name":"one"},{"id":"102","name":"two"},{"id":"103","name":"three"}]
list2   =[{"id":"111","name":"one"},{"id":"112","name":"two"},{"id":"114","name":"four"},{"id":"115","name":"five"}]
```

In the above two lists contains duplicate name values . now i want to get the unique name objects based on name attribute.
OutPut:-

```
result   =[{"id":"103","name":"three"},{"id":"114","name":"four"},{"id":"115","name":"five"}]
```

Comment: You show JSON syntax yet have tagged your question C#. Can you elaborate on whether these are C# or JSON lists, and what you have tried to resolve this?

Comment: You could concatenate the 2 lists, then `GroupBy(x => x.name)` and get the values where `Count == 1` although if your object has a `IEqualityComparer`, then there are other alternatives such as combining `.Except()` and `.Union()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could using `Linq` extension functions and do this.

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2)
     .GroupBy(x=>x.name)
     .Where(x=>x.Count() == 1)
     .Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault())
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var common = list1.Select(a => a.name).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.name));
```

Comment: This only selects the name property (OP wants the object)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have list of model after JSON deserialization process:

```
var list1 = new List<Model>();
var list2 = new List<Model>();
```

Since you need to remove all elements that intersect in each list and returns unique elements, use either Except or RemoveAll:

```
var target = list1.Except(list2);

// or use:
var target = list1.RemoveAll(item => list2.Contains(item));
```

Another way using HashSet:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<Model>(list2);
list1.RemoveAll(item => hashSet.Contains(item));
```

Reference: [Remove elements from one List<T> that are found in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295483/remove-elements-from-one-listt-that-are-found-in-another)