# Remove elements from one list that are found in another

Tags: c#

This should be quite easy, however I am failing to see why all my methods are not working.

I have looked at all the solutions and used them appropriately however am not getting the result.

solutions include

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182123/linq-query-form/9182183#9182183)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295483/remove-elements-from-one-listt-that-are-found-in-another)

Here is the code:

```
IEnumerable<feature> available = _repo.GetAvailableFeatures();
IEnumerable<feature> selected = _repo.GetSelectedFeatures();
```

Using Except

```
var filteredList = (available.Except(selected)).ToList;
```

Using Linq

```
var availableList = available.ToList();
var selectedList = selected.ToList();
availableList.RemoveAll(item => selectedList.Contains(item));
```

Using old fashion for

```
for (var i = 0; i < availableList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            foreach (var t in selectedList)
            {
                if (availableList[i].Id == t.Id)
                {
                    availableList.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

My Feature class looks like this:

```
public class Feature
{
 public int Id;
 public int Desc;
}
```

Can anyone see it my mistakes here?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: (assumes database access instead of in-memory objects) `Feature` doesn't override `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode`. All items are considered unique.

Comment: You need to either Override `Equal` and `GetHashCode` in `Feature` class or Use a a custom equality comparer and then use `Except`.

Comment: Sorry. The AvailableList do not remove the feature in SelectedList.

Comment: One assumes `feature` is a complex object type. When doing an object comparison, .Net will consider the objects to NOT be equal unless they are in fact the same instance. As others have said, you will need to define how the objects should be compared (overriding the `.Equals`) to get the code to behave the way you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Except` you need to define what "equal" means for the `feature` type, otherwise reference equality (are they the same object) is used by default.  In your loop you define "equal" as "`Id`s are equal", so some options are:

- Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the `feature` class

  - This becomes the "default" definition of equal for the type
- Define a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<feature>`

  - This could be used only when that definition is needed
- Use `Where` instead of `Except`:

  ```
  var filteredList = available.Where(a => !selected.Any(s => s.Id == a.Id))
                              .ToList();
  ```

  - Performance is sub-optimal but it is a simpler code solution if performance overall is not affected significantly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a straightforward process of comparing the two data lists to each other and removing them in a standard fashion. I would personally go with a List setup instead of IEnumerable.

```
List<Feature> availableList = _repo.GetAvailableFeatures();
List<Feature> selectedList = _repo.GetSelectedFeatures();
foreach(Feature avail in availableList){
    if(selectedList.Contains(avail)){
        selectedList.Remove(avail)
    }
```

Comment: I have not tried this solution atm thus I have not marked as answer. Will test it tomorrow

Comment: Unfortunately, further looking at it, it seems like there is slight issue with the logic. 
It should be the availableList that should be removing the item which appears on the selectList. I have changed the code accordingly however, it still does not work. 
 foreach (var avail in selectedFeatureList)
            {
                if (availableFeatureList.Contains(avail))
                {
                    availableFeatureList.Remove(avail);
                }

            }